# Rails 2 Datatable serverside processing with AJAX

Tags: ajax, datatable, ruby-on-rails-2

In Rails 2 Application I want to implement Jquery datatable with serverside processing and using ajax .

I am following railcast episode 340 and https://github.com/JoelQ/ajax-datatables-rails
but they are for rails 3 and I am using rails 2
So any one give me the good ideda or Example is Good for me.

Thanks

Comment: You could download datatables.js from http://www.datatables.net/download/ and just include the library in your layout header. Is that not ok for you? Or do you want to wrap the data tables in a gem to use it with bundler?